# Reproduce nested Excel Pivot table in r with tabular

Tags: r, tabular

I am trying to reproduce the following excel pivot table in r:
[image: Excel pivot table]

Using tabular:

```
library(vcd)
library(tables)
tabular(Sex*(Treatment+1)+1~(count=ID + Percent("col")), data=Arthritis)
```

Produces:

```
              count        
 Sex    Treatment ID    Percent
 Female Placebo   32     38.10 
        Treated   27     32.14 
        All       59     70.24 
 Male   Placebo   11     13.10 
        Treated   14     16.67 
        All       25     29.76 
        All       84    100.00
```

Is there a way to get the treatment percents to add up to 100 for each gender like the excel pivot table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything apart from the final `All` row can be accomplished with the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

   df <- Arthritis %>%
  group_by(Sex, Treatment) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(Treatment, cnt) %>%
  mutate(All = Placebo + Treated) %>%
  gather(Treatment, ID , -Sex) %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  mutate(percent = ID / (sum(ID) / 2)) %>%
  arrange(Sex, desc(Treatment)) #forces "Treated" to top of Treatment column for each group

    > df
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: Sex [2]

     Sex Treatment    ID   percent
  <fctr>     <chr> <int>     <dbl>
1 Female   Treated    27 0.4576271
2 Female   Placebo    32 0.5423729
3 Female       All    59 1.0000000
4   Male   Treated    14 0.5600000
5   Male   Placebo    11 0.4400000
6   Male       All    25 1.0000000
```

If you want a total line, you can use the following, but it isn't very pretty.

```
grand_total <- data.frame(Sex = "Total" , "Treatment" = "All", 
                          ID = nrow(Arthritis), percent = 1, 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_final <- bind_rows(df, grand_total)
```

Now, if you want to blank out the `Sex` column except for the first, occurrence, you can do it this way. Since we sorted in decsending order on the `Treatment` column, we know that `Treated` it as the top of each group. So we simply replace the `Sex` column with a blank when the `Treatment` column is not equal to `Treated`. We also don't blank out the `All` we created.

```
df_final$Sex[df_final$Treatment != "Treated" & 
df_final$Sex %in% c("Female", "Male")] <- ""

Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
Groups: Sex [3]

     Sex Treatment    ID   percent
   <chr>     <chr> <int>     <dbl>
1 Female   Treated    27 0.4576271
2          Placebo    32 0.5423729
3              All    59 1.0000000
4   Male   Treated    14 0.5600000
5          Placebo    11 0.4400000
6              All    25 1.0000000
7  Total       All    84 1.0000000
```

Comment: If you would like to remove the `All`s in the `Treatment` column, you can do so with a simple `%>% filter(Treatment != "All"` at the end of the creation of the `df` object. Not sure if that is the goal or not, though.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Is there a way to remove the duplication of Female and Male after the first line they appear?  The goal is to replicate the look of the Excel pivot table output.

Comment: I have updated the code to blank out the `Sex` row except for the first instance.